# Is there a canonical way to decorate services in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, decorator

I'm coming from the Symfony world. Symfony has some very nice tools for handling decorators, and they're well documented.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

Is there any equivalent, official source of truth on how to set up Laravel decorators?

Googling around, I've seen a couple GitHub repositories that purport to do service decoration in Laravel, but I'm not aware of whether these are the "official" way to do it in Laravel, in the way that the page linked above is the "official" Symfony way. I'm thinking of putting together a talk on the two frameworks' approaches, and I want to make sure I'm not leading people astray by suggesting the wrong practices.

===

EDIT: Just to be clear, I'm talking about decorating -- which involves having an "inner" class and decorating the output -- rather than extension of a class. Extension has its place, but it's not what I'm hoping for here.

Comment: no, you have to do it yourself ... but decorator pattern was pretty common years ago so i am sure there are resources to show some examples ... since we have an IoC container you can return what ever decorator you need based on bindings

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Common way - bind decorator to interface of base class in SP and just pass inner object in his constructor. Symfony is really overengenered..